# Selenium - Open two same websites with same credentials

Tags: java, selenium

How can i open multiple similar websites with same credentials using selenium and perform tasks parallelly.

Comment: is that application support it?

Comment: you don't need to pass credential again just take that page URL and open it in a new tab through selenium web driver and upload your files one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Use Selenium Grid and run multiple tests/tasks at the same time / in parallel.

[Selenium Grid](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)